# AngularJS: Universal listener to handle any event

Tags: javascript, events, angularjs

On any event-centered application it's fairly easy to reach a point of complexity where one loses track of all the events fired, handled and inhibited (aka propagation stopped).

So, for tackling this problem, my question is: is there a way of listening for any event? I was thinking of something like this (invented):

```js
$rootScope.$on('*', function (event, data) {
  console.log('Event fired: ' + event.name)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built into Angular that lets you do this. Your best bet is probably to build a service that wraps $rootScope's event methods and adds its own logging around them.

Comment: I wish there was a nicer and more thorough way to track events. I've implemented your suggested approach for now. Thanks.